# Scatter Random Variables "Nicely" with n=10

Tags: combinatorics, regression

Find 3 sets of 10 random numbers such that each set has a variance that is an integer, and their co-variance must also be an integer.

Do you need to write an algorithm to find all possible combinations or is there a way to set up the problem "on paper" to come up with at least some of the possible solutions?

The motivation  is to find nice sets of numbers to practice simple linear regression by hand calculation so that you a student does not end up with numbers that are awkward to calculate (or that simply cancel themselves out for some nonsensical scatter diagram).

I would also appreciate a more formal or correct way to state the problem.

Comment: How do you define the covariance of two (or three) *sets*?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/idea:** If all numbers in a set of $n$ numbers are integer multiples of $n$, then the mean and variance of this set will be integers.

Comment: I like the hint rather than the answer!  Thanks.  So let's say n = 10. That means only 1,2,5,10 are multiples of 10.   That doesn't make for a very interesting dataset.  Draw from the set (1,2,5,10) ten times.  Am I misunderstanding the hint?

Comment: @Hexatonic I said multiples, not divisors...

Comment: Ok, I get it.  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100] and [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] don't make for very interesting practice sets.   Also, the variance of [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] is 62.5

Comment: @Hexatonic The variance of the second set is 50, not 62.5

Comment: Oh man, I must be using the python statistics library wrong: statistics.variance( [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] ) yields 62.5.

Comment: @Hexatonic Probably it uses the unbiased estimator for variance with factor $\tfrac{1}{n-1}$ instead of the more intuitive biased one with $\tfrac{1}{n}$. You can take numbers that are multiples of both $n$ and $(n-1)$ if you want variances to be integers with either estimator.

Comment: Sounds like I need to take a Introduction to Mathematical Statistics course